# С++. Представление указателей в памяти

Tags: c++, указатели, память

Предположим, есть класс `Item`. Создадим объект класса и указатель на объект:

```
Item object = new Item();
Item *ptObj = new Item();
```

Теперь мы можем обращаться к членам, используя `.` и `->` для `object` и `*ptObj` соответственно.

Собственно, вопрос: 
Как представлены `object` и `*ptObj` в памяти?

Comment: Вот это `Item object = new Item();` у вас точно компилируется? (если конечно, явно не заданы конструкторы `Item() {};` и `Item(Item*) {};`)

Comment: Сам объект представляет собой структуру, состоящую из всех нестатических полей класса. Указатель на него представляет собой его адрес в памяти, размер адреса зависит от архитектуры: 32 бита на x86-32 и 64 бита на x86-64 соответственно.

Answer (score 2):

Вот это

```
Item object = new Item();
```

у вас не скомпилируется, если только вы не объявили конструктор `Item::Item(Item *item)`. Но сейчас не об этом. Думаю вы имели ввиду

```
Item object;
```

Эта запись создает в стеке объект класса Item.

А вот тут

```
Item *ptObj = new Item();
```

вы объявляете в стеке переменную типа указатель и помещаете в неё адрес объекта созданного в куче.

Основное различие заключается в том, где находится объект `Item`. В первом случае он находится в стеке. Во втором случае — в куче по некоторому адресу, который хранится в переменной `ptObj`, которая, в свою очередь, расположена в стеке.

Comment: `Item object;` это не обязательно в стеке.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian, имеете ввиду случай когда это поле объекта в куче?

Comment: еще когда это глобальная переменная, или как `static` объявленная..

Answer (score 1):

Указатель в памяти является числом, которое при этом является и некоторым адресом. Динамически созданный объект, вполне вероятно, будет являться выделенной областью памяти.